# JHipster - Role Management

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, roles, jhipster

I would like the following behavior of role management using JHipster.

- Daniel is an user
- Daniel has assigned 2 group of roles (admin and normal user)
- The group of roles called admin has the following permissions: CREATE_USER, OTHER_FEATURE
- The group of roles called normal user has the following permissions: CREATE_X, CREATE_Y

In this case, Daniel has in fact 4 permissions: CREATE_USER, OTHER_FEATURE, CREATE_X and CREATE_Y.

As far as I know, JHipster has only support between user - permission, but there is no the concept of group of roles. Am I correct? Is there a possibility of create a concept of group of roles instead of select one by one of permissions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The concepts of user and authorities are defined by spring security not JHipster, you'll find many articles about how it can be adapted. Then the user management UI will have to be changed.